# Unchecked input checkbox with identical ids

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the values of an input of type checkbox with the same ID, and try to get the click (the checked), to the one with the value 1

but when I do the console.log I only get the value of the first input and it does not get both values.

i.e. to bring me the value number 2 of the first one and not 2 and 1.

```
                            <script>
                                var s = document.getElementById("switchA").value;
                                console.log(s);
                            </script>
```

These inputs are of checkbox type so if one of them has value two it should be unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="asd" id="switchA" value="2">

<input type="checkbox" name="asdf" id="switchA" value="1">
```

Comment: "with the same ID" — That is not allowed in HTML. Don't do that.

Comment: id should be unique - but if you cant change it for some reason, and the names are different try: ```var s = document.getElementsByName("asd");```  ref: ```https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be giving the same id to multiple elements on a page. However, assuming you are not able to change the HTML, you can use the following to select multiple elements with the same id:

```
var s = document.querySelectorAll("[id='switchA']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `name` or `class` instead to group the checkboxes. Ids are meant to be unique in a document.

```js
const vals = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name=someName]')]
               .map(x => x.value);
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="someName" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="someName" value="1">
```

However, you could use an attribute selector to obtain all elements with a specific id, but that is not recommended.

```js
const vals = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id=switchA]")]
               .map(x => x.value);
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="asd" id="switchA" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="asdf" id="switchA" value="1">
```